# Why is the result of the promise still `undefined` after execution?

Tags: javascript

Why is the result of the promise still `undefined`? Tutorial says it's gonna be `error`.
Is it a Chrome display issue or anything I don't comprehend so far?

[image]

Comment: The `promise` has the result `Error`. The `promise.then(…)` has not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from the error handler (`alert` returns `undefined`), so the Promise result tied to the error is `undefined`. If you return something from the error handler, you'll see it in the result.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject('err');
  }, 1000);
})
```

[image]

It's not a Chrome thing - this is how it'd work in any environment. (To access the error result, call `.catch` on the Promise and use the first argument)

Comment: I ran over the tutorial and realized the promise result is gonna return the value of the rejection. Thanks for your enlightenment.